# How to get an event when all internal bindings in custom element ready in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've got custom element

```
<maillist-chain-extended id="chain_extended" messages="{{maillist}}"></maillist-chain-extended>
```

Each time attribute "messages" changes, all internal elements will redraw itself.

```
 <dom-module id="maillist-chain-extended">
      <template>
      <paper-material elevation="4" id="maillist-chain-extended">
        <array-selector id="array_selector" items="{{messages}}" selected="{{actual_chain}}" toggle></array-selector>
        <maillist-chain-header content="{{actual_chain}}"></maillist-chain-header>
        <div class="b-maillist-chain-quantity">{{actual_chain.Messages.length}}</div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{actual_chain.Messages}}" as="chain_item">
          <div class="b-maillist-chain-item-wrapper">
            <maillist-chain-item-header item-content="{{chain_item}}"></maillist-chain-item-header>
            <maillist-chain-item-full item-content="{{chain_item}}"></maillist-chain-item-full>         
          </div>
        </template>
      </paper-material>
    </template>
    </dom-module>
```

I want to make some changes in its DOM after all internal templates will be stampted, but how can I do that if `dom-change` event handler on  will handle all `dom-change` events of internal elements? I need 1 event that fires when all internal DOM is ready.

Thank you

Comment: Use the `ready` callback or fire a custom event using `this.fire('event', data)`

Comment: @Ricky make that an answer so it can be accepted! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ready` callback or fire a custom event using `this.fire('event', data)`

### or

Use `Polymer.dom.flush()` to [interrogate the DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) after any DOM manipulation you perform.

Comment: it's ok on the first time, but when I change property of an element and it renders again how can I catch time when all internal elements are updated and fire custom event or handle system event of all custom element children changed its DOM? Thank you, Ricky

Comment: I've catched all internal dom-change events and stop its propagation, so I have only 1 dom-change on custom element when updating data, but it seems not so cool^)

Comment: Can you share more code in your question so I can get a better idea of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've find a solution:

1. Prevent all internal dom-change events
2. run

   this.async( function() {
      handler();
   });

on custom-element

Comment: Try using `Polymer.dom.flush()` to ensure the DOM is stamped out post DOM manipulation. Check my amended answer. Preventing events could have negative impacts down the line.

Comment: @Ricky I agree with you, but are you sure that flush() is the right way for solving my problem where we have templates to redraw itself. Can you write short example of your solution? Thank you